Swipe to Delete Not Working Consistently Across Fragments in ViewPager
I'm developing an Android application with two fragments in the tablayout managed by ViewPager in a single Activity. I'm experiencing inconsistent behavior with the swipe delete functionality for items in a RecyclerView in these fragments.
I have two fragments:

SpendingFragment
PurchaseGoalsFragment

When I swipe to delete an item in the fragment that is currently visible, I expect the item to revert to its original position (unswiped state) immediately after being swiped, as I am not yet actually removing the item (just observing swipe behavior). This works as expected for the fragment that is currently in view. However, if I switch between these fragments (e.g., reorder them in the ViewPager), only the fragment that is currently visible behaves correctly. In the other fragment, items remain in the swiped state and do not return to their original position after the swipe.
Expected Behavior:
After swiping an item in either fragment, the item should return to its original state immediately (without removing the item). This should happen regardless of which fragment is currently visible.
Actual Behavior:
The item in the fragment that is not currently in focus remains swiped and doesn’t revert to its original position, even though notifyItemChanged(position) is called in the onSwiped method. This behavior is inconsistent across the fragments.

I’m using a custom SwipeToDelete class that extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback. Here’s a simplified version of that class:
class SwipeToDelete(
    private val swipableAdapter: SwipableAdapter,
    private val icon: Drawable?, // Background Icon
    private val backgroundColor: Int, // Background Color
    private val cornerRadius: Float // Corner radius for the card
) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = backgroundColor
        isAntiAlias = true
    }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        swipableAdapter.onSwiped(position)
    }
}

Here is my SwipableAdapter interface implemented by my adapters:
interface SwipableAdapter {
    fun onSwiped(position: Int)
}

Here is the adapter class of my first shown fragment:
class PurchaseGoalsAdapter(
    private val goals: MutableList<PurchaseGoal>,
    private val moneyBox: MoneyBox
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GoalsAdapter.ViewHolder>(), SwipableAdapter {

    // ... (other code)

    override fun onSwiped(position: Int) {
        notifyItemChanged(position)
        println("PurchaseGoals adapter swiped: $position")
    }

    // Other methods...
}

Here is the adapter class of my second shown fragment:
class SpendsAdapter(private val spendsList: List<Spend>, private val moneyBox: MoneyBox) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<SpendsAdapter.ViewHolder>(), SwipableAdapter {

    // ... (other code)

    override fun onSwiped(position: Int) {
        println("Spends adapter swiped: $position")
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

    // Other methods...
}

Log Output
2024-10-05 15:25:52.635 11061-11061 System.out     I  PurchaseGoals adapter swiped: 0
2024-10-05 15:25:56.185 11061-11061 System.out     I  Spends adapter swiped: 0

How can I ensure that items in both fragments revert to their original position after being swiped, regardless of which fragment is visible?

Use a ViewModel cross activity and fragments to store your tab index, once tab  index changed, reset your list item's swipe state to idle.
For example:
class TabViewModel:ViewModel(){
    val tabId = MutableStateFlow(0)
}

//in activity
private val tabViewModel:TabViewModel by viewModels()
fun onCreate(...){
   //...
   // reference to you tab layout
   val tabs = ...
   tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                tab?.id?.let { 
                    tabViewModel.tabId = it
                }
            }
            // ...
        })
}

// in each fragment
private val tabViewModel:TabViewModel by activityViewModels()
fun onViewCreated(...){
    //...
    lifecycleScope.launch{
        tabViewModel.tabId.collectLatest{
             // reset your list item's swipe state to idle here.
             resetItemSwipeState()
        }
    }
}


